# jQuery UI datepicker modify text node

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to modify the text node for a given day when having a datepicker.

For example I have this view:

[image: DatePicker view]

And I would like to be able to access the text node for given date, so to modify it, to look like this: [image]